# Content of highchart tooltip getting overflow

Tags: javascript, highcharts, salesforce, bubble-chart

Content of the tooltip getting overflow, even though no external style getting applied.

[image]

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
                width: '100px',
                whiteSpace: 'normal'
            },
            
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            borderColor: '#DEDFE0',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 1,
```

Please help me to fix the content inside modal.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?

Answer (score 0):

You are fixing the width to 100px. You should try removing the fixed with or try something like max-width instead.